# Will postgreSQL supports rest API?

Tags: java, postgresql, rest

I want to know whether PostgreSQL provides support for rest or is there any other way to achieve it?

Comment: PostgreSQL is an RDBMS, it has nothing to do with REST! But it has JDBC drivers available, so use such a driver with a Java API which does REST and you're set. Strange question, really. After that, which Java ORM (hint: use [JooQ](http://www.jooq.org)) and REST-able API you use is up to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres doesn't support an REST interface out of the box. But there is an early draft about adding one: [Postgres Wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/HTTP_API) So Postgres might add one in a future version. 
There are some "experiments" for it on Github: [link](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/postgresql-http-server)

**Right now there are two viable solutions:**

1. Use a third party tool, that provides a rest api for postgres.
   [restsql](http://restsql.org/doc/Overview.html) would be an example.
2. Implement your own Webservice layer.

It depends on your requirements which way to go:

(2) offers you the most control. You can design the api the way you need it. Modern Java Frameworks (JPA, JAX-RS, Jackson etc.) make it fairly easy and efficient to create a lightweight API layer.

(1) would be viable if you only need a basic way to access a DB over REST.

Answer (score 8):

Another project that try to solve this is [PostgREST](https://github.com/begriffs/postgrest). It's written in Haskell not Java, but you can use it from Java using ordinary HTTP requests.

> PostgREST serves a fully RESTful API from any existing PostgreSQL
>   database. It provides a cleaner, more standards-compliant, faster API
>   than you are likely to write from scratch.

Comment: Just found [ToroDB](https://github.com/torodb/torodb), also worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Disclamer: I am an owner of the product in the answer.</sub>

Hello,

You might want to check out https://zenite.io, a database host platform that supports REST endpoints for querying the database data.

For example, you can create an API endpoint `/user` and define a SQL query on it:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $id;
```

and then execute a GET request on the database server:

```
https://server.zenite.io/user?id=1
```

This URL would return the data in the JSON format:

```
[
    {
        "rows": [
            {
                "Id": 1,
                "FirstName": "John",
                "LastName": "Doe",
                "Age": 30
            }
        ],
        "code": 0
    }
]
```

The supported technologies include PostgreSQL, among others.